# Get screen dimensions

Tags: android

I am trying to get the screen dimensions or density this way:

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point mdispSize = new Point();
mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
int maxX = mdispSize.x;
int maxY = mdispSize.y;
```

The problem is that the maxY contains the navigation bar so my bitmap background is under the navigation bar.

How can I get the maxY without navigation bar height?

Comment: Is there a chance of the app being used in split screen?

Comment: No, it´s a simple game. I´m just trying to paint a canvas.

Comment: In that case, you can just use the root view's height. You can get it using `view.getHeight()`.

Comment: Or better still, use a full screen activity.

Comment: Using getHeight works perfectly, but trying to make the activity Fullscreen gives me the same problem ,so i will use getHeigth(). Thank you!

Comment: Do accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height of the parent view:

```
view.getHeight()
```

and use it.